# Stirling number

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I am trying to evaluate the following finite sum:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}(k-1)!S(n-1, k-1)(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}H_{i}),
$$
where $S(n, k)$ are the Stirling's numbers of the second kind and $H_{i}$ denotes the $i$ harmonic number. Could you please shed some light?

@Gerry Myerson

I think that the first few terms obey the sequence http://oeis.org/A001787 with alternating signs.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the first few to see what they look like?

Comment: I guess the last sum should start at $i=1$?

Comment: Either $0$ or $1$, as $H_{0}$ is by convention $0$.

Comment: I don't know how much this will help you, but $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}H_{i} = k(H_k - 1)$... you can see it easily by calculating $(k+1)(H_{k+1} - 1) - k(H_k - 1)$

Answer (score 1):

Your OEIS guess is correct.
The trick is looking at this formula for Stirling numbers of the second kind:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \brace k} (x)_k = x^n$$

(I'm using [Pochhamer symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol))

and noticing that Pochhamer symbol turns out to be really simple for some special values:

$$ (-1)_n = (-1)^n n! $$
$$ (-2)_n = (-1)^n (n+1)!  \ \ \ (*)$$

This gives us a few surprising identities:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \brace k} (-1)^k k! = (-1)^n$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \brace k} (-1)^k (k+1)! = (-2)^n$$

That's nice, but I still haven't solved your question, right? Your OEIS sequence looks like $n 2^{n-1}$ - comparing this and few last identities you see it's a derivative of some kind.

This is how harmonic numbers enter the game. Notice:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x)_n = (x)_n \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac1{x-k}$$ (just using the multiplication formula for derivation).

Just differentiate the very first formula I wrote in this post, put $x = -2$ and use identity $(*)$!

Comment: Thank you. This is an elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

It may  interest the reader that  this sum can be  evaluated using the
technique of *annihilated coefficient extractors* (ACE).

Start with
$$q_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \times (k-1)! \times
{n-1 \brace k-1} \times \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} H_j$$ 
and introduce the generating function
$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} q_n \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

Recall the  bivariate generating function  of the Stirling  numbers of
the second kind which is
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

Substitute this into $Q(z)$ to get
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \times (k-1)! \times
(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \times 
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} H_j.$$

This immediately simplifies to 
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} z^{n-1}
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \times
[z^{n-1}] (\exp(z)-1)^{k-1} \times
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} H_j.$$

Switch summations to obtain
$$\sum_{k\ge 1} (-1)^k \times
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} H_j \times
\sum_{n\ge k} z^{n-1} [z^{n-1}] (\exp(z)-1)^{k-1}.$$

The   inner  sum   contains  the   promised   *annihilated  coefficient
extractor* and everything simplifies to
$$\sum_{k\ge 1} (-1)^k \times
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} H_j \times  (\exp(z)-1)^{k-1}.$$

Switch sums one more time to obtain
$$\sum_{j\ge 0} H_j \sum_{k\ge j+1} (-1)^k (\exp(z)-1)^{k-1}$$
which is
$$- \sum_{j \ge 0} H_j \frac{(1-\exp(z))^j}{1-(1-\exp(z))}
= - \exp(-z) \sum_{j\ge 0} H_j \times (1-\exp(z))^j.$$

Now  ask when  the term  $1/q$ occurs  in the  harmonic number  $H_j =
\sum_{q=1}^j 1/q$ to obtain
$$- \exp(-z) \sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{1}{q} \sum_{j\ge q} (1-\exp(z))^j.$$
This is
$$- \exp(-z) \sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{1}{q} \frac{(1-\exp(z))^q}{1-(1-\exp(z))}
= - \exp(-2z) \sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{1}{q} (1-\exp(z))^q
\\ = - \exp(-2z)
\log\frac{1}{1-(1-\exp(z))}
= z \times \exp(-2z).$$

We are done and we may conclude by extracting coefficients to find
$$q_n = (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \quad z \times\exp(-2z)
= (n-1)! [z^{n-2}] \exp(-2z) \\
= (n-1)! \times \frac{(-1)^{n-2} 2^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}
= (-1)^n \times (n-1) \times 2^{n-2}.$$

This is indeed [OEIS A001787](https://oeis.org/A001787) up to signs:
$$0, 1, 4, 12, 32, 80, 192, 448, 1024, 2304, 5120, 11264, 24576,\ldots$$

There is another computation with *annihilated coefficient extractors* at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836964/a-sum-for-stirling-numbers-pi-e).

Comment: Thanks and good luck with your problem. You can always post it as a question (which I prefer) in case you don't succeed.