# How to analyze this recursion?

Tags: recursion

How can I analyze this recursion for $k>0$?
$$T(n)=n+T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+\cdots+T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)$$

I want to prove that $T(n)=\theta(n\log(n))$.

Is it true that $T(n)=n+\frac{n}{2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2}=n+\frac{n}{2}\log(n)$?

*I got it by iterations method of these*:

\begin{align}T(n)&=n+T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+\cdots+T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)\\  
T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)&=\frac{n}{2}+T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)+\cdots+T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\right)\\
T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)&=\frac{n}{4}+T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{32}\right)+\cdots+T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k+2}}\right)\\
T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)&=\frac{n}{8}+T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{32}\right)+\cdots+T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k+3}}\right)\\
&\vdots\end{align}

Comment: You're almost there.  How many $\frac{n}{2}$'s do you have?  One for each $T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k}}\right)$.  But there are only logarithmically many of these since you only need to take this out until $2^k$ is larger than $n$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $k$ is fixed here, for example, $k=42$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr log(n) , because $\frac{n}{2^k}=1$ --> k=log(n) ? but, how can i deal with the given that k is fixed?

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted your question.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This question also appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557714).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = \frac{n}{2} + T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \cdots + T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\right) \tag{$1$}
$$
and
$$
T\left(n\right) = n + T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \cdots + T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k}}\right) \tag{$2$}
$$
By $(2) - (1)$, we have
$$
T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n}{2} - T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\right) \tag{$3$}
$$
implying (if $T(n) \geq 0$ for all $n$)
$$
T(n) \leq 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n}{2}
$$Thus by master theorem,
$$
T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n \log n)
$$

---

We can not conclude $T(n) = \Omega(n \log n)$ if $k$ is fixed. As a counterexample, when $k = 1$, we have
$$
T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n
$$
and in this case, $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: thank you, and how can you prove that $T(n)=Ω(nlog(n))$ while $k=log(n)$?

Comment: @Mathing I assume the logarithm base is $2$. Then $$T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\right) = T\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ which is a constant. Then you can apply the master theorem for equation $(3)$ immediately.