# Lower and upper asymptotic bounds

Tags: computational-complexity, recursion

i have the following question:

> Find lower and upper asymptotic bounds for the following recursive function:
>
> $T(n)=n+T(\frac{n}2)+T(\frac{n}4)+...+T(\frac{n}{2^k})$

For the upper and lower bounds, can i say that:$$T(n)\le{n+kT(\frac{n}2)}$$
$$T(n)\ge{n+T(\frac{n}{2^k})}$$
And then continue by opening the function? If not, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this post? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557714/find-o-and-omega-bounds-as-tight-as-possible-for-tn-nt-frac-n-2t-fr?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, but i didn't understand the solution, we haven't learned the methods used by the people who answered